# Are stop motion quesitons on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

See for example [What features does a camera need to be used for good quality stop-motion animation?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35568/what-features-does-a-camera-need-to-be-used-for-good-quality-stop-motion-animati)

Stop motion is an area that *definitely* blurs the line between still photography and video. Should we redirect these questions to [Audio-Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) or keep them here?

Answer (score 11):

I'm of the opinion that these are generally fine for this site, as more so than most video stop motion is very much about *a series of stills*.

Questions about composing the video and syncing audio and so on may be better for our sister site, but the process of staging and taking the photos seems fine on Photo.

Answer (score 1):

Equipment recommendation for a camera to take stills ought to be on topic for sure.